# Generalizing Cauchy-Schwarz inequality and Hölder's inequality for concave functions

Tags: inequality, convex-analysis, cauchy-schwarz-inequality, integral-inequality, holder-inequality

We know that $$E[x^2] > E[x]^2$$ by Cauchy-Schwarz. Further we know that $$E[x^2]E[\sqrt{x}] > E[x]E[x^{1.5}]$$ when $x$ is restricted to positive reals by Callebaut's Inequality or Hölder's inequality. Can we prove that for all concave and positive functions $f$ such that $f(0) = 0$ we have $$E[x^2]E[f(x)] > E[x]E[xf(x)]$$

where $x$ is only supported on $(0, 1)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The inequalities are large.

I denote by $X$ the random variable, and by $Y$ an independent copy of $X$. I only assume that $X$ is non-negative and in $L^2$, so all expectations are finite.

We note that
\begin{eqnarray*}
2E[X^2]E[f(X)] - 2E[X]E[Xf(X)] 
&=& E[X^2f(Y)] - E[XYf(Y)] \\
& & + E[Y^2f(X)] - E[YXf(X)] \\
&=& E[(X-Y)(Xf(Y)-Yf(X))].
\end{eqnarray*}

Because of the concavity of $f$ and the assumption $f(0)=0$, the random variable $(X-Y)(Xf(Y)-Yf(X)$ is null on the event $[XY=0]$ and non-negative on the event $[XY>0]$ since $f(Y)/Y-f(X)/X$ has the same sign as $X-Y$.

The desired inequality follows.